# Mistake in these notes? Cannot verify that the two regions are the same

Tags: real-analysis, laplace-transform, convolution

In there [notes](https://www.vyssotski.ch/BasicsOfInstrumentation/LaplaceTransform.pdf) you find the following claim (bottom of page 33):

[image]

I cannot verify that $D = \mathcal D$. I've drawn them over 5 times now in different ways and I always get the same result:

$D$ is the area below $r=t$ and $\mathcal D$ is the area above $r=t$.

But if this was correct, one cannot exchange an integral over $D$ for one over $\mathcal D$ because any function is not guaranteed to be the same in both areas.

**What am I missing?**

I need this for the integral in the proof of the Laplace convolution theorem.

Comment: You are right: in $D$, if $t=0$, $r$ can take any nonnegative value, while in $\mathcal D$, if $t=0$, then $r=0$. This implies that $D\setminus\mathcal D$ is not empty (it contains $(1,0)$ for example), so the sets are different. Does the proof works with $\mathcal D=\{ (r,t) : 0\le r<\infty, 0\le t\le r \}$?

Comment: @Taladris The proof seems to exchange one set for the other! If the sets are not equal, this is wrong, right?